# Automate JAR execution that requires python interpreter

Tags: java, linux, shell

**Scenario :** 
 I have a Referee.jar program which I got from somewhere (making a point that I don't know to change that code). Also, I have 2 python files which I've written.

**Currently :** 
 The JAR file has to be executed first in the terminal with "java -jar referee.jar" and then "python 1.py" and "python 2.py" have to be typed into the following lines.

**Requirement :** 
 I want to make a shell script which will do that and store the output into a file called 'out.txt'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here.
[Automatically answer to input prompt in windows batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40610241/automatically-answer-to-input-prompt-in-windows-batch)

Just had to echo the file names and redirect it to the command.
My sincere apologies for not checking this before posting the question.