# How to pass a password along with a ssh command in a Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh, cmd

I have a port forwading command which, when I run it in Windows Command Prompt, responds with a password input request.

I need a way to send password along with the command when invoked from a batch file.

e.g.

```
C:\Users\smith>ssh -f 10.92.21.183 -L 5432:127.0.0.1:5432 -N -l admapp
admapp@10.92.21.183's password:
```

PS.
I tried below links but not working:

1. [Automatically answer to input prompt in windows batch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40610241)
2. [How to auto answer prompts in Windows batch script](https://thirutechie.blogspot.com/2009/10/how-to-auto-answer-prompts-in-windows.html#:%7E:text=Windows%20batch%20script-,To%20auto%20answer%20prompts%20in,script%2C%20try%20the%20following%20command.&text=Ex%3A%20The%20del%20%2FP%20command,manual%20input%20to%20proceed%20further)

Comment: Have you considered setting up SSH keys instead.

Comment: Thanks @Squashman , actually I need it to run my automation code on VM . So I am planning to pass this from my jenkins job as I wont be knowing on which executor / VM my code will run so setting up SSH keys dont seem an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible **only** with *Batch Script* ,or **without configuring ssh**.

Because once the `ssh` command is invoked, that statement(process) is being held until the password is provided and will not let you call another process until it's(`ssh`) executed.

So, the quickest and easiest way to get you through the ssh password this way would be to create a script that will copy the password in your clipboard(*not safe*) beforehand and execute the ssh command. So that when you are prompted for password you will be ready to paste it with `Ctrl+v`.

Save the code below in a file called bssh.bat and put it in the path, and save your password in a password.txt textfile somewhere and change the location in the script below accordingly `path\to\the\password.txt`, so when you press bssh, then it should run the ssh command and copy the password into the clipboard for you:-

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('type "path\to\the\password.txt" ^| clip ^&^& ssh -f 10.92.21.183 -L 5432:127.0.0.1:5432 -N -l admapp') do %a
```